# C# encode bitmap JPEG and save it to byte[]

Tags: c#, encoding, bitmap, jpeg

I have this code that saves an image to disk

```
public static void SaveImage(Bitmap picture, string path)
    {

        // Comprimir
        ImageCodecInfo encoder = GetJPGEncoder();

        // Create an Encoder object based on the GUID
        // for the Quality parameter category.
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =
            System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

        // Create an EncoderParameters object.
        // An EncoderParameters object has an array of EncoderParameter
        // objects. In this case, there is only one
        // EncoderParameter object in the array.
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

        //picture.
        picture.Save(path, encoder, myEncoderParameters);

    }
```

but now I need to get the result as a byte[]. I can't find a way to get the result in memory so that I can convert it to byte[]. I thought about loading the file after saving it in the harddrive, but that would be completely unnecessary. Does anyone know if I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `MemoryStream`.  One of the overloads of the `Save()` method takes a `Stream`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    picture.Save(stream, encoder, myEncoderParameters);
    return stream.ToArray();
}
```